# Rejected Payflow Silent Post does not void a transaction in PayPal processor

Tags: paypal

If there is a problem with the data we receive in a PayPal Manager silent post, we return a 401 (UNAUTHORIZED).

We have the 'Void transaction when my server fails to receive data sent by the silent post' setting enabled.

When we return a 401, we see that the transaction is voided in the PayPal Manager interface (transaction report shows the Sale followed a few seconds later by a Void).  However, the Sale still goes through in our main PayPal account (we are using PayPal Internet Merchant Account as the transaction processor).  So the customer still gets charged, even though we voided in PayPal Manager.

I suspect this is some issue between PayPal Manager and PayPal Internet Merchant Account, but I have no idea how to get help for this.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

The desired outcome is that if we return anything but a 200 in the response to the silent post that the transaction will be voided everywhere and our customer will not be charged.

Comment: Seems a question for Payflow/PayPal support. Give them specific examples to look at.

Comment: @PrestonPHX it does seem that way, doesn't it?  I've spent hours on the phone with their tech support without any resolution.  Was hoping someone else may have encountered this and had some suggestions.

Comment: Use https://www.paypal-support.com/s/contactsupport?language=en_US , leave request/response examples with PNREF/PPREF and preferably with debug/correlation IDs. Silent post might give a debug id in the HTTP headers, not sure